# Extend a TypeConverter

Tags: c#, .net, typeconverter

The DateTimeConverter class provides conversions between DateTime and string. I would also like to support conversions between DateTime and double.

According to MSDN I can extend the DateTimeConverter class to do this - see [MSDN DateTimeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.datetimeconverter.aspx)

I have created a class that inherits from DateTimeConverter and provides the appropriate overrides for CanConvertTo, CanConvertFrom, etc.

How do I make sure that the framework uses my DateTime converter (DateTimeConverterEx) instead of the one provided in the BCL (DateTimeConverter) when the code below is called?

```
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    // This line returns a DateTimeConverter which I don't want. 
    // Would like to get a DateTimeConverterEx.
    TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(dt);
    double dbl = (double)tc.ConvertTo(dt, typeof(double));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just declare a new instance of the tyep converter directly as such?

TypeConverter tc = new MyConverter();

Is there a specific reason why you need to call the method of TypeDescriptor?

Comment: I'm using TypeConverters because I have an object reference that could be any number of types (not just DateTime). Using TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(obj) gives the correct converter. Marc's answer below is perfect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to allocate the converter. On a property-by-property basis, you can use:

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(DateTimeConverterEx))]
public DateTime Foo {get {...} set {...}}
```

This would then work for usage of the form:

```
var prop = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj)["Foo"];
var converter = prop.Converter;
// as before, using "converter"
```

This will work for most common binding scenarios.

(**edit**)

To set the converter for **any** `DateTime`:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(DateTime),
    new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(DateTimeConverterEx)));
```

Now your sample code should work.