# c# create and attach dll to project

Tags: c#, c++, multithreading, winapi, dll

I want to create a class library project in C# and attach it to a procces.

I've already did this in C++, my code is

```
#include <windows.h>
void Thread()
{
// here i just do my stuff
}
int WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinst, unsigned long reason, void* lpReserved)
{
    if(reason==DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
         CreateThread(0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)Thread, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This works very well for me.

Is possible to do this in C#?

Thanks, I hope i'll find an answer and accept it.

Comment: .Net process or do you want to host CLR?

Comment: Maxwell i don't really understand your comment. I want to make a mod for a game. Using the C++ code above, I get a .dll file, add it to the game folder and the dll will be attached and that thread will start. I want to do the same with C#.

Comment: What I meant was: is it all c# or mix of c++ and c#?

Comment: I want to do all in C#.

Comment: This is probably what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137781/c-sharp-correct-way-to-load-assembly-find-class-and-call-run-method

Comment: I don't want to create a DLL dynamically.. i just want to create it normaly, with F6.. and I want it when is attached to a procces to start a thread..

Comment: Not sure what F6 does but anyway.. That doesn't create a DLL. Loads an already existing one. And I found this as well. Seems better option than static constructors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/505237/net-running-code-when-assembly-is-loaded ..anyway, interesting question. Good luck.

Comment: You code is broken in C++ anyway. That's not a thread proc. The fact you had to cast it is a tell tale sign.

Comment: @MaxwellTroyMiltonKing do you know how can I implement that? Copying some code from will only give me errors..

Comment: @Paul Module initializers aren't supported in C# - you'd need to use C++/CLI...

Answer (score 2):

C# doesn't have a mechanism such as `DllMain` where you can execute code when referenced or used from an executable.  The executable will need to explicitly call a method on (or at least use) a type within your library in order for your code to execute.

If you know a type within your library is going to be used, however, you can "cheat" and get your thread to start by placing it within the static constructor for that type.  This will cause it to execute at or before the first usage of that type.

That being said, if you're writing the exe that's going to use this C# library, you can just call a method on a type that begins your thread and starts your work.

Comment: Is not working...I saved the library as a .DLL file (well I did F6), copied the DLL to the game folder that i want to load it (GTA). And when I start the game i hear no beep...if I create a DLL with C++ and the code in the question it works..

Answer (score 1):

Follow the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206736/c-sharp-equivalent-of-dllmain-in-c-winapi).

> Give your class a static constructor and do your initialization there.
>   It will run the first time anybody calls a static method or property
>   of your class or constructs an instance of your class.

Comment: Well, this is my code. Is it good? http://pastebin.com/5qFqs01z . The problem is that that file is not created..

Answer (score 1):

Soulds like you can use [module initializers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2005/11/19/494914.aspx). Unfortunately C# doesn't support them. You will have to inject the IL, for example using a tool like [Module Initializer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/InjectModuleInitializer/) or [Fody](https://github.com/fody/)