# Execute init function when assembly(dll library) gets loaded, execute clean up function when it gets unloaded

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I have a dynamic-linked library in C# that will be loaded by other libs or apps. The init function needs to be called to allocate/initialize resources when the assembly(dll) is loaded and the cleanup function needs to be invoked before the assembly is unloaded.

I am looking for something in C# that is similar to `DllMain` function in C++ that you can call functions in the event of `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` and `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should follow this link 

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8206736/c-sharp-equivalent-of-dllmain-in-c-winapi

Comment: @JulianCr I am using the static constructor now, but how about the cleanup function? where should I put it? I am wondering if there is any alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on your scenario.

You can use the  AppDomain.ProcessExit event in the static constructor.

something like:

```
 class MyClass  {    
      static MyClass() {
           AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit +=
               MyClass_Dtor;    }

       static void MyClass_Dtor(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            // do here some clean up   
  } 
}
```

The AppDomain.ProcessExit is not guaranteed to be called.

See more details about AppDomain.ProcessExit here

[AppDomain.ProcessExit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/11/26/process-exit-event.aspx?Redirected=true)