# Can we use global.asax file in DotNet class library projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, clr

Can we use `Global.asax` file in `.NET` Class Library projects? Because I have not seen anywhere that `Global.asax` file can only be used only with Web based applications.

The code of `Global.asax` file are being complied and being called by .net framework when application starts. I want to use similar kind of functionality with my class library i.e. when my class library is being loaded in the memory the `Application_Start` of `Global.asax` file of class library will be called.

I know that this can be used using static constructor but I want to utilize the `Global.asax` for this.

Any suggestions/comments will be highly appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: Using a `Global.asax` for a class library would be weird. Why do you need initialization code? What are you trying to do?

Comment: class libraries aren't applications that "start", they are simply a single file (.dll) that holds a collection of classes.  Normally any initialization code that these classes might need would be done in their constructor.

Comment: Global.asax isn't some mystery code that is run because it must be run, it is run by IIS because IIS knows that such code is the initialization routine for some service. So you can just as easily apply some add-in(plugin) model with strictly defined initialization, cleanup routines that will be called when you load add-in dlls through appropriate mechanisms.

Comment: Thanks for comments,  Yuval. I understands that libraries are not application that's why i used Load not initialized. libraries loads , i think it is similar to as Applications starts.

Comment: So basically global.asax should not be work with class library projects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `global.asax` file is a feature of ASP.NET appliations. It is not available in DLLs (class library projects).

There is no standard way (using C#) of running some code on assembly-load, even though the CLR seems to have such a feature. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459560/initialize-library-on-assembly-load) for some more information and ideas. For example, one answer mentions a tool called [InjectModuleInitializer](https://github.com/einaregilsson/InjectModuleInitializer), which is run as a post-build step to inject a module initializer method into a .NET assembly.

Here's a short excerpt from the [blog post introducing InjectModuleInitializer](http://einaregilsson.com/module-initializers-in-csharp/):

> One feature of the CLR that is not available in C# or VB.NET are
>   module initializers (or module constructors). A module initializer is
>   simply a global function which is named .cctor and marked with the
>   attributes SpecialName and RTSpecialName. It is run when a module
>   (each .NET assembly is comprised of one or more modules, typically
>   just one) is loaded for the first time, and is guaranteed to run
>   before any other code in the module runs, before any type
>   initializers, static constructors or any other initialization code.

Comment: Even Visual Studio does not allow to add Global.asax file with Class Library type projects.

Comment: @user2147315: If you think the answer was helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer (also with your other questions). Thanks.

Comment: Yes... I have marked it as answer.. I also wanted to give +1 but I do not have sufficient reputation..:)